# Toggle visibillity of dynamically loaded sub views in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF user control that should display different sub views / sub-usercontrols. The main user control (aka Switcher) displays both a ComboBox containing all the sub views and all the sub views below the combobox (see the graphical illustration below, the colors are just to see the relationship. Note: I don't actually want to display **all** the sub views when the combobox is opened, this is just to illustrate that *they are there*).

[image]

[image]

Whenever the selected index of the ComboBox is changed, I want to display the correct sub view, and hide all the other sub views, and **my main question is what the best way to do this would be**?

**Complication:** The sub views are given to the Switcher at run time (they are plugins that are loaded), so I don't know at design time / compile time how many or which views I will need to display. Therefore my regular approach with wiring up boolean properties in the view model and using a BooleanToVisibilityConverter would not work (I guess?).

So, I have two related questions:

1. How can I easily show/hide the sub-views based on the selection in the ComboBox?
2. Is my current architecture flawed, and if so, how could it be improved?

I'm using MVVM, and my current code is included below. Yep, I know I'm using a small code behind to wire up everything, and I don't want to be slapped for that (unless if it causes the architecture-problems):

**Switcher (view, code behind):**

```
// NOTE: plugin-views are given to the view when initialized, and this method
// is called once per plugin / sub view

/// <summary>
/// Adds a formatting view to the switcher
/// </summary>
/// <param name="view">The view to add.</param>
private void AddFormattingView(UserControl view)
{
    // Add the control to our view model
    _viewModel.AddFormattingView(view, "<The view label>");

    // Add the formatting view to our view's extension point
    // NOTE: ExtensionPoint is basically a StackPanel defined in XAML
    // Perhaps this is where my architecture is flawed? That I should rather
    // display this from the view model with a data template or something similar?
    ExtensionPoint.Children.Add(view);
}
```

**Switcher (view, XAML):**

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Width="100" Content="{Binding Label}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </DockPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="ExtensionPoint" x:FieldModifier="public" />
</StackPanel>
```

**View model:**

```
// NOTE: INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented to notify the view etc
// NOTE: I'm not showing the model, since it is pretty straight forward

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the index of the selected formatting view.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The index of the selected view.
/// </value>
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return _model.SelectedIndex; }
    set { _model.SelectedIndex = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets a read only copy of the formatting view items
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The formatting view items
/// </value>
public IReadOnlyList<FormattingViewSwitcherItem> ItemsSource
{
    get { return _model.Items; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Adds a formating view to the switcher.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="view">The formatting view to add.</param>
/// <param name="label">The label of the view.</param>
public void AddFormattingView(UserControl view, string label)
{
    _model.AddFormattingView(view, label);       
}
```

**FormattingViewSwitcherItem:**

```
/// <summary>
/// A class holding information on items in the formatting view switcher
/// </summary>
public class FormattingViewSwitcherItem
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public UserControl View { get; set; }

    //..
}
```

Comment: A quick question: do the subview VMs have different types? If so, a simple solution with `DataTemplate`s can be possible.

Comment: @Vlad Yes, the subview VMs have different types, and they all implement a common interface. However, I don't know those types at design time, they'll be loaded at runtime (e.g. third-parties can extend this with their own plugins where the VM types are unknown to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this would work for you:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Width="100" Content="{Binding Label}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </DockPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentContainer">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary />
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
    </StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
```

The resource dictionary inside the last stackpanel must contain the mappings of the VM types into the user controls. This can be achieved if the plugins returned not just a view, but a resource dictionary like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type plugin:VM1}">
        <plugin:UserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you can add each of the resource dictionaries to the `MergedDictionaries` of `ContentContainer.Resources`.

Or may be these resource dictionaries have to be added to the Application's resources, so that all the code would be able to resolve plugin's VM into the appropriate UserControl.

---

It may actually work without the resource dictionary trick if the content presenter knows how to show the VM. This way, we can do without setting `Resources`.

Comment: Thank you. I've not worked a lot with resource dictionaries. Could you please elaborate on "This can be achieved if the plugins returned not just a view, but a resource dictionary like this". Should the XAML be included in the XAML of the plugin view? And how exactly can I extract that resource dictionary to merge it into the resource dictionary of the ContentContainer?

Comment: @Gedde: It should be like this. (1) Plugin code defines a resource dictionary like it's in the answer. The target type is the type of VM which the plugin provides, and the usercontrol is the control prepresenting the VM. (2) Plugin can load a dictionary through its [pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with code like `new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(""pack://application:,,,/PluginAssembly;component/Folder/File.xaml") }`

Comment: @Gedde: (3) If now the plugin provides you with UserControl instance, it should provide instead the resource dictionary created at (2). You can use it as follows: `ContentContainer.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resdict)`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This worked great. Actually, it worked with just the ContentPresenter alone (i.e. even when I removed all the resource dictionaries etc it worked as I wanted). Perhaps the answer should be updated in order to reflect that?